# Objective-C dictionary argument is not an NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have this line of code here:

```
punchList = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:[[[areaData GetPunchListDataArray:communityDesc] objectForKey:@"Root"] objectForKey:@"KeyValue"]] autorelease];
```

but this gives me an error when I run it:

```
dictionary argument is not an NSDictionary
```

when I do this:

```
punchList = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:[[areaData GetPunchListDataArray:communityDesc] objectForKey:@"Root"]] autorelease];

    punchList = [punchList objectForKey:@"KeyValue"];
```

I get no error and punchList gets populated, how come its not working the first way I did it.

Comment: Why are you still using `autorelease`? What happened to ARC?

Comment: Are you following an old tutorial? You dont need autorelease anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be clearer if you break the code down into separate statements with separate variables.  The failing example can be broken out as:

```
punchListDataArray = [areaData GetPunchListDataArray:communityDesc];
rootObject = [punchListDataArray objectForKey:@"Root"];

// This is not dictionary, so next line fails
possibleDictionary = [rootObject objectForKey:@"KeyValue"]; 
punchList = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:possibleDictionary] autorelease];
```

The second set of statements can be broken down as:

```
punchListDataArray = [areaData GetPunchListDataArray:communityDesc];
rootObject = [punchListDataArray objectForKey:@"Root"]; 
// A different variable is being used to initialize
punchList = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:rootObject] autorelease];
punchList = [punchList objectForKey:@"KeyValue"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Just because the line `punchList = [punchList objectForKey:@"KeyValue"];` doesn't give you an error doesn't mean that the result is correct.

Try this:

```
punchList = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:[[areaData GetPunchListDataArray:communityDesc] objectForKey:@"Root"]] autorelease];
punchList = [punchList objectForKey:@"KeyValue"];
NSLog(@"punchList is now a %@", [punchList class]);
id someValue = [punchList objectoForKey:@"SomeKey"];
```

Running that code should crash with a message about an unknown selector `objectForKey:` on some class. And the console will show the log message telling you what `punchList` really is at that point.

The reason is the same reason your first block of code fails. And that is because the result of:

```
[[[areaData GetPunchListDataArray:communityDesc] objectForKey:@"Root"] objectForKey:@"KeyValue"]
```

is not an `NSDictionary`.